# Cannot edit Plone content with TinyMCE on IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce, plone

Tested on:

- Plone 4.0.7 or Plone 4.2
- Internet Explorer 9 upgraded
- TinyMCE 1.1.10

When I edit a simple Plone document with IE 9 (only) in the body text, changes are not saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please upgrade your [`Products.TinyMCE` package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.TinyMCE) to version 1.3b4, versions before 1.3 are not compatible with Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: How to upgrade ? I try to change version.cfg (1.1.10 to 1.3b4) but it's always the 1.1.10 installed

Comment: @bklups: Add a `Products.TinyMCE = 1.3b4` line to the `[versions]` section of your buildout, or upgrade the version number if there already is a `Products.TinyMCE = <version>` line there.

Comment: Products.TinyMCE 1.3b4 is correctly installed with your recommandations but after running my instance on fg i have : ImportError: No module named hooks

Comment: Try with 4.2. You can also try and file an issue with the developers at http://dev.plone.org/, I believe they want the package to work with Plone 4.0.x as well.

Comment: @bklups: I see that there is a [fix for that issue](https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/commit/f0743975dcefd865f1febc27909fac11b8f79c87). You can try to apply that patch in the egg.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, it works with the 1.3b5, it's strange that Plone dev don't upgrade to 1.3

Comment: The TinyMCE update cycle took place in a separate repo for a while to work out a refactoring. It wasn't ready for the Plone 4.2 cycle, but 1.3 will be part of Plone 4.3.